# Cocoa Bindings (MonoMac C#)

Tags: c#, cocoa, macos, binding, monomac

I'm using cocoa for the first time (i'm using it through MonoMac), so I'm having problems understanding how I can do this:
I have some text fields with some data binded to it (using Cocoa bindings, and a Object Controller), the problem is that I want to making changes in those textfields saved only when I press a button, but I can't figure how I can do this, as for now when I change the text in a textfield those changes are automatically commited when I leave the textfield..

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you were able to get your issue resolved posting the solution as an answer to your own question would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty tough to help you without looking at your source code. Zip the project and ask help on mono-osx mailing list (just send an email to mono-osx@lists.ximian.com; you have to first register on http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/mono-osx). It will be then easy to look into your code and figure out the problem.

I'm more than willing to help you if you can somehow show me what you have done so far.